# iptables NAT - one public IP to multiple local IP (same port)

Tags: unix, routes, iptables

Let's say I have one gateway server connected to Internet (one public IP `XX.XX.XX.XX` - `*.mydomain.com` is pointing to it); and two web servers A & B connected (`192.168.0.1` and `192.168.0.2`) and running `apache2`.

On the gateway, all http trafic is currently redirected to server A:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i em3 -p tcp --dport  80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i em3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:443
```

(And this is working perfectly)

---

### What I need

I am slowly migrating the webserver from server A to server B. At the moment, I have multiple subdomains (`*.mydomain.com`) pointing to server A, and I'm planing to moove each website step by step to server B.

At a given time, when customer go on `site1.mydomain.com`, the `www/` folder could be still on server A, or already on server B.

- I want to edit NAT rules on the gateway so both webserver would be queried to answer a given http request.

---

### What I tried

I might be yound and naive, but I though I could do the same NAT to server B, so when I go on `siteY.mydomain.com`, the traffic is going on both webserver, and the one with the vhost is displaying the webpage. I tried with those rules:

```
# server A - rules already used
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i em3 -p tcp --dport  80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:80
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i em3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.1:443
# server B - new rules
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i em3 -p tcp --dport  80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:80
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i em3 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.2:443
```

But I think both are ignored, because every request is still landing on server A.

---

### Questions

**1.** Is-it possible to "duplicate" the trafic to go on both webservers? (maybe it's dumb, sorry)

**2.** Can I tell to the gateway something like "*if its for site1.mydomain.com, stay on server A; but if it is for `site2.mydomain.com`, go on server B*"?

**3.** What is the best solution to achieve this goal ?

I cannot make the gateway to run apache. And ideally:
I don't want to use diferent ports;
I don't want to edit server A nor B iptables.

Feel free to correct me or ask more detail if needed!

---

Sources/clues:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/830366/multiple-servers-behind-gateway-and-nat
- https://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial
- I heard something about a reverse Apache proxy?

Comment: Hi, IPtables always only evaluates the rules until the first match. If you want to redirect the traffic based on the domain, you would need a reverse proxy. NGIX would be a good lightweight solution for that!

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this not through iptables because you could end up having to inspect the https SNI to see what hostname is being requested, so maybe a solution (and if your application supports it) would be setting up a proxy (maybe nginx) that could also offer tls termination.

for nginx a simple server with this rule could be enough:

```
server{
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name site2.example.com;
    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Singlesite true;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.0.2;
    }
 }


server{
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name site1.example.com;
    location / {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Singlesite true;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass $scheme://192.168.0.1;
    }
 }
```

Also maybe depending on your migration process there could be better ways to do this.